# UITableView - switch data from two arrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I'm working on an application in which I have a UITableView, two arrays and one UISegmentedControl. Now I need to when the UISegmentedControl value is 0 loaded in the UITableView data from the array one, and when UISegmentedControl has value 1 loaded data from array two. Simply, I need to switch the data to be loaded into UITableView from arrays. I tried to use a bool, but it does not work, I also think that it's not ideal.

**Here is my code:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    allTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                    [[Food alloc] initWithName:@"BWM" andDescription:@"Auto" andDefinice:@"Osobni"],nil ];

    allTableData2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                    [[Food alloc] initWithName:@"Renault" andDescription:@"Dodavka" andDefinice:@"Velka"],nil ];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    long rowCount;
    if(self.isSwich == false)
        rowCount = allTableData.count;
    else
        rowCount = allTableData2.count;

    return rowCount;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    Food* food;
    if(self.isSwitch  == false)
    {
        food = [allTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        food = [allTableData2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = food.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = food.description;

    return cell;
}
-(IBAction)switchdata:(id)sender
{
    if(self.myswitcher.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {
        isSwitch = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        isSwitch = TRUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain the "does not work" part in a bit more detail?

Comment: Data are not switch. UITableView displayed data from one array, but when I click on UISegmentedControl nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a call to `reloadData` in the `witchdata:` implementation. Adding this call will fix the problem.

> I also think that it's not ideal.

That's right. Rather than storing a flag that says which array to use for your data source, store the array itself. This would eliminate all the `if`s on the `isSwitch` property:

```
// Declare this as an instance variable, and use it
// in your data source methods.
NSArray *theSource;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    allTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                    [[Food alloc] initWithName:@"BWM" andDescription:@"Auto" andDefinice:@"Osobni"],nil ];

    allTableData2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                    [[Food alloc] initWithName:@"Renault" andDescription:@"Dodavka" andDefinice:@"Velka"], nil];
    theSource = allTableData;
}

-(IBAction)switchdata:(id)sender {
    if(self.myswitcher.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        theSource = allTableData;
    } else {
        theSource = allTableData2;
    }
    [myTable reloadData];
}
```

Alternatively you could make `isSwitch` an integer, and use it as an index into an array that has your `allTableData` at index zero and `allTableData2` at index one:

```
NSArray *sources;
int sourceIndex;
// Use sources[sourceIndex] as the current source

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    allTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                    [[Food alloc] initWithName:@"BWM" andDescription:@"Auto" andDefinice:@"Osobni"], nil];

    allTableData2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                    [[Food alloc] initWithName:@"Renault" andDescription:@"Dodavka" andDefinice:@"Velka"],nil ];
    sources = @[allTableData, allTableData2];
    sourceIndex = 0;
}

-(IBAction)switchdata:(id)sender {
    sourceIndex = self.myswitcher.selectedSegmentIndex;
    [myTable reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, in your switchData: method - use self.switch to access its setters,getters.

Secondly, Rather than using a bool value to track segment value, use the direct segment value.
Replace your self.switch value with self.switcher.selectedSegmentIndex in the table view delegate,datasource methods.

Finally, reload table view in your switchData: method.